# Gradient not smooth in Safari and Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, safari, gradient, linear-gradients

I'm trying to use a linear gradient for the background of a page:

```
body {
  background: linear-gradient(10deg, #060f14, #002725);
}
```

This looks great in Chrome and Opera (+iOS Safari and mobile Firefox), but in desktop Safari and Firefox the blending is not smooth and looks really ugly.

[In Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/px74O.png)

[In Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfWHe.png)

is there a way to smooth the gradient out on desktop Safari and Firefox?

Comment: a sidefact: its also good to put an prefix on linear gradient like `-webkit-` and `-moz-` and`-o-`

Comment: That's known as banding, and is quite normal for linear-gradients. To avoid this, UAs should apply dithering (like Chrome does). I know FF had this as a plan, but they had issues with it: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=627771 Dunno for Safari though. But anyway, no easy solution on your side...

Comment: @Ifaruki Browsers support gradients without prefix since 2013, so for the last 7 years. So no need to put any prefixes for gradients at all.

Comment: @TemaniAfif this is not the same case here. This question deals with how gradients are generated fundamentally, it's not just a container height issue, OP could try with an inner container and still face the same issue. Now there could be dupes, but that one is not the one.